# How do I do authentication for my powershell scripts for Microsoft 365/AzureAD/Exchange Online automation?

Tags: powershell, multi-factor-authentication, microsoft365

So I can successfully run commands to manage our Microsoft 365/AzureAd/Exchange Online - this involves assigning and removing license, converting user to a shared mailbox, delegating access to a mailbox, etc. I followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/mfa-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) for authentication. But that's me actually logging in with my credentials + MFA (Multi-factor authentication) for authentication.

I want to have a script that does these type of actions triggered by a schedule. I believe I can include the credentials but how to do MFA? Tried to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/multi-factor-auth?view=partnercenterps-3.0) but getting error ***clientid is not a guid*** I have registered an app in https://portal.azure.com/ and able to do Graph API calls using that. No luck in PowerShell authentication though. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. A potential solution is to set some rules where in specific case, MFA will not be required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office365/PowerShell-Script-to-4081ec0f)?  It should allow you to connect to all Microsoft online services and includes support for MFA.  If it does not work, the website has many other scripts you can try

Comment: Thanks @williamhiggs ! Those are actually good scripts. However, still need to log-in and populate MFA interactively which I'm trying to find a way around.

Comment: @ticsroboau I think I see what you are going for.  You want to automate the entire mfa authentication process.  I don't believe that that is possible.  You might want to see if it is possible to create a service account with the appropriate permissions to accomplish what you want....